# Getting person addresses from other objects using the references

Tags: java, object, constructor, reference, pass-by-reference

Retrieve addresses from other objects by reference.

Hello, I am struggling with a particular task. Well I had two classes to do, address and person data (informations). For both classes I created constructors along with the option to display information on the screen.

Address class:

```
public class adres {
String postalCode;
String street;
String city;

public adres(String postalCode, String street, String city){
    postalCode = postalCode;
    street = street;
    city = city;
    System.out.println("Address: \n" + "Postal Code: " + postalCode + "\nStreet: " + street + "\nCity: " + city + "\n --------------------------------- \n");
}
```

}

Person class:

```
public class person {
String name;
String surname;
int phone_number;

public person(String name, String surname, int phone_number){
    name = name;
    surname = surname;
    phone_number = phone_number;
    System.out.println("Client data:\n" + "name and surname: " + name + " " + surname + "\n" +"Phone number: " + phone_number + "\n");
}
```

}

In the main file I contained the objects, which later initialized using the constructors. The starter file code looks like this:

```
public class starter {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String name1 = "John";
    String surname1 = "Bush";
    int phone_number1 = 575332114;

    person data1 = new person(name1,surname1,phone_number1);

    String postalCode = "47-321";
    String street = "Washington St.";
    String city = "Washington";

    adres info1 = new adres(postalCode,street,city);

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------

    String name2 = "George";
    String surname2 = "Denis";
    int phone_number2 = 338729416;

    person data2 = new person(name2,surname2,phone_number2);

    adres info2 = info1;
    info2 = new adres(postalCode,street,city);


    //-------------------------------------------------------------------

    String name3 = "Tom";
    String surname3 = "Rolling";
    int phone_number3 = 165776879;

    person data3 = new person(name3,surname3,phone_number3);

    String postalCode2 = "17-221";
    String street2 = "Green St.";
    String city2 = "York";

    adres info3 = new adres(postalCode2,street2,city2);

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------

    String name4 = "Eric";
    String surname4 = "Murble";
    int phone_number4 = 335757449;

    person data4 = new person(name4,surname4,phone_number4);

    adres info4 = info3;
    info4 = new adres(postalCode2,street2,city2);
}
```

}

To the two Persons I've assigned previous addresses using references.  The idea was: if the address is taken from another object (and if it already exists) then assign the value from that object by reference. Did I do it correctly? The code compiles correctly, but I'm wondering how to improve it and what disadvantages the current solution has (for example, one of them is definitely the lack of conditional instructions, but I wasn't supposed to use them).

Is anyone able to confirm my reasoning - and should the references look the way I presented it in the code? Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: A `Person` (class name should be capital) does not have an `adres` field, so it's not clear what _To the two Persons I've assigned previous addresses..._ means.  Also, code like `adres info2 = info1;` isn't needed since the next line assigns `info2` to a new instance.

Comment: @AndrewS Thank you for your comment. What I meant with "To the two Persons I've assigned previous addresses..." was that the requirement was that at least one address had to be assigned to two persons. 

I did it so that Person1 has the same address as Person2, and Person3 has the same address as Person4

Comment: There is no connection between a `Person` and an `Address`.  Perhaps an Address needs to be added to the `Person` constructor, so an `Address` can be stored on the `Person`?  For example: `Address anAdress = new Address(...); Person person1 = new Address(..., anAddress);  Person person2 = new Address(..., anAddress);`.  This will make `person1` and `person2` share the same `Address` instance (assuming that was the intent).